# Azure Pipelines: can a template be consumed from a pipeline resource rather than a repository resource?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

The Azure Pipeline documentation on templates and usage has a section about [consuming templates from other repositories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#use-other-repositories) using a 'repository' resource.  I would like to do something similar, but use a [pipeline resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#resources-pipelines) (published artifact) instead of a repository resource.
Unfortunately, I can't get it to work.  The `common.yml@templates` syntax seems specific to repositories and I was unsuccessful downloading the artifacts and referencing them by path (likely because the [template is evaluated before any steps are run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runs?view=azure-devops#process-the-pipeline))

Is it even possible to consume templates from other resources besides repository types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, it is not possible to my knowledge, you can only do that from another repo as the schema suggests (if you could, schema would show that)